# Condensing sparse geocodes to weighted Geo-Circles?

Tags: google-maps, geoprocessing, geocoding, circle, generalization

I have a dataset comprising 3 million records having latitude and longitude information associated with them. I want to condense it to form few thousands Geo-Circles, with radius and weight depending upon the records comprising in it.

Any suggestion regarding this kind of approximation algorithm or tool helping to build this?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to [cluster points by spatial proximity?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=cluster+point)

Comment: Yes, exactly I need to cluster these points by their spatial proximity, any existing solutions on this ?

Comment: The link (in my previous comment) leads you to several dozen solutions :-).

Comment: Thanks! I am going through each link, but wondering how I could scale these algorithms up-to 3 million records, as resulting circles will be each of dynamic radii.